# JOLT Transformation - Remove leading zeros from String

Tags: json, jolt

I have a example input:

```
{
  "number": "0000000000068908"
}
```

or an other example input:

```
{
  "number": "0012000000034458"
}
```

Is it possible to remove the leading zeros from string via jolt transformation to get the following output ?

```
{
  "number": "68908"
}
```

or

```
{
  "number": "12000000034458"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry for the late reply,there are several ways to reach that, one I can imagine is turn the string into a numeric value(e.g. a long int) after this, the zeros to the left will be removed, and then you can use that result and convert it  to string again.

here you can play:

http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#modify-typeConversion

and here the demo:
json:

```
{
  "number": "0000000000068908"
}
```

Jolt Spec:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "number": "=toLong"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "number": "=toString"
    }
  }
]
```

result:

```
{
  "number" : "68908"
}
```